# New iOS SDK 3.0, Posting to a user's wall without deprecated API

Tags: ios, facebook

I'd like to know if there is a proper way to post a message to a user's wall with the new SDK.
From what I understand there is no way anymore to display a message preview with a dialog view to the user before posting.
I'd rather not using deprecated API. I followed the tutorial for login in with Facebook with the new SDK (importing the Framework etc). When it comes to post a message they ask to import the deprecated Facebook.h header (and its friends...) but it generates lot of compilation errors because some classes are named the same.
Do you people use the deprecated API?
Or do I have to create a custom view myself to display a preview to the user and then use the FBRequest method `+ requestWithGraphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod:` to perform the post "in the background"?

Comment: I'm afraid it now looks like Facebook want everyone to build their own custom views to display previews, as outlined in this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Comment: Please check out our new SDK release 3.2 here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/25/facebook-sdk-3-2-for-ios/ We now have support for Native web dialogs without using the deprecated headers. You can checkout this class: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBWebDialogs which has methods to get you started on this. For sample code, please check BooleanOGSample as part of our SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Facebook SDK 3.2, it is now possible to display a native dialog with the new classes available in the SDK. Have a look to [FBNativeDialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBNativeDialogs), [FBShareDialogParams](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBShareDialogParams) and [FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple. This worked for me:

**We need not import the deprecated headers at all.** By using only the latest facebook ios sdk 3.0 following is what you can do.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",fbid]
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id     result,NSError *error) 
{

  NSLog(@"error %@ \n\n\nresult = %@",error,result);

}
```

*fbid* is the profile id of the user. You can give the friend's profile id in order to post on his wall.

In case you have to post on the user's own wall, you can either give the *graph path* as @"me/feed" or as stated above (by giving the *fbid* as the user's profile id)

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain a bit more or is there any way we can talk a bit?

Comment: @revanth Does this call actually present a user interface for a preview and let the user edit of the Facebook post before it gets sent, or does this just perform the posting of it online? People resort to the deprecated headers because they want the preview/edit feature without writing their own UI, not because they can't actually do the post...

Comment: @Rob No it does not. It is just an API call.

Comment: @revanth, this call no longer works after Facebook's February 2013 Breaking Changes. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/ The only way to post to a friend's wall is via the Feed Dialog and using the Deprecated Headers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I couldn't find a way around importing the deprecated headers, like the tutorial says. After importing both the framework and Facebook.h with friends, clean your project to make sure the linker doesn't complain about the same file names.

The [apprequests tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) still explicitly says to import deprecated headers. So I don't think FB wants you to implement your own views. I would assume they had to release 3.0 and posting to wall and apprequests weren't finished, so they now have this hybrid 3.0/deprecated system until they finish the rest.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Getting loads of redefinition errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. I was #importing Facebook.h but still had an #import <FaceBookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> in another file. Removing this one solved it.

Comment: Yeah you can't mix #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> and #import "Facebook.h".  I did all that just for access to FBDialog.  Fun!