# presentFeedDialogModallywithSession does not post message to a friend

Tags: ios, facebook

Iam using the following code to post a message on my friend's facebook wall. This code posts message to the logged in users wall but not to the friend's wall

Iam also giving the "to" value and i.e., friends facebook id (116623456) and App_id but same problem persists.

Please provide a good direction on this.

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender   
 {
       NSLog(@"DonePressed Called");
       NSString* fid;
       NSString* fbUserName;

       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have been selected as a       health coach(Multiple Users1), You will be receiving daily and weekly reports from here on!!!!"];


       NSLog(@"Before For");

//   NSString *SelectedFriends = nil;
for (id<FBGraphUser> user in _friendPickerController.selection)
{

    fid = user.id;
    fbUserName = user.name;


     NSLog(@"User Name =%@, USer id =%@",fbUserName, fid);


}
NSLog(@"After For");
NSLog(@"%@",fid);

NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"4444444444444444",@"app_id",
fid,@"to",
nil];
// Invoke the dialog


[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
         NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
         } else {
             // Handle the publish feed callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Share button
                // Show the result in an alert
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                             message:@"Message Posted Successfully"
                                            delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil]
                  show];


             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
    // at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class
    for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {
        if ([text length]) {
            [text appendString:@", "];
        }
        [text appendString:user.name];

        NSString *fid=user.id;
        NSString *fbUserName=user.name;

        NSLog(@"");

        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test miLineup!", @"message", @"Iphone Apps", @"name", nil];

        NSLog(@"\nparams=%@\n", params);

        //Post to friend's wall.
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", fid] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
             //Tell the user that it worked.
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shared"
                                                                 message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invited %@! error=%@", fbUserName, error]
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
         ];

        //Close the friend picker.
        //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: I have used this code but it gives me HTTP status code error 403 and one more question... Is startWithGraphPath not depricated from March 2013

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792427/new-ios-sdk-3-0-posting-to-a-users-wall-without-deprecated-api
  this call no longer works after Facebook's February 2013 Breaking Changes. developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes The only way to post to a friend's wall is via the Feed Dialog and using the Deprecated Headers. – Scott Lieberman Apr 22 at 21:49